# azure Release copy single file to wwwroot folder

Tags: azure, dll, copy, release, wwwroot

I am currently trying to copy 3 dll's into a plugins folder below the wwwroot folder. But I can't find a way to do this. I already have FTP Upload, Deploy Azure App Service and Copy. Can someone give me a tip on how to copy the files from $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/_Masterdata/drop/server to wwwroot/plugins?

Regards

Michael

Comment: What resource its your target? A VM, app service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the solution. The FTP task works fine for this task. What did not work is the copy button in the Azure interface. It never copied the password and therefore my FTP did not work.
But thanks to all who have looked at this.

Here the ftp task. For which you also have to configure this

[image]